# Curry two different but similar functions

Tags: javascript

I have two different but similar functions that make an api call.
I'm wondering if there is a way to curry them?

```
const getNameMatches = async partialName=> {
  const { data: documents} = await axios.get(
    `api/Documents/SearchDocument?searchString=${partialName}`,
  );
  const { data: clients } = await axios.get('api/Clients/GetAll');
  return documents.map(document=> ({
    label: document.Name,
    subLabel: clients.find(c => c.id === document.clientID)?.firstName,
    value: document,
  }));

const getAddressMatches = async partialAddress=> {
  const { data: documents} = await axios.get(
    `api/Documents/SearchDocumentByAddress?searchString=${partialAddress}`,
  );
  const { data: clients } = await axios.get('api/Clients/GetAll');
  return documents.map(document=> ({
    label: document.propertyAddress,
    subLabel: clients.find(c => c.id === document.clientID)?.firstName,
    value: document,
  }));
```

I combined the two functions into one function but I would want to curry them and wondering if this is possible.

The combined function:

```
const getMatches = async (state, partialString) => {
  const tabValue = state.tabValue;
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `api/Documents/SearchDocument${
      tabValue === 'Address' ? 'ByAddress' : ''
    }?searchString=${partialString}`,
  );
  const { data: clients } = await axios.get('api/Clients/GetAll');
  return data.map(loan => ({
    label: tabValue === 'Name' ? document.name: document.propertyAddress,
    subLabel: clients.find(c => c.id === loan.clientID)?.firstName,
    value: document,
  }));
};
```

Comment: yes this is correct too.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I look for...

Answer (score 1):

the only difference is the API URL and the label.

So you can collect them and make it generic

```
const getMatches = async (partialValue,type)=> {
  let urlString="",label="";
  if(type==='name'){
        urlString="SearchDocument";
        label="Name";
   }else{
        urlString="SearchDocumentByAddress";
        label="propertyAddress";
   }
  const { data: documents} = await axios.get(
    `api/Documents/${urlString}?searchString=${partialValue}`,
  );
  const { data: clients } = await axios.get('api/Clients/GetAll');
  return documents.map(document=> ({
    label: document[label],
    subLabel: clients.find(c => c.id === document.clientID)?.firstName,
    value: document,
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want [currying](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400), you can do something like this:

```
const searchFor = type => {
  const path = type === 'name'
    ? 'SearchDocument'
    : 'SearchDocumentByAddress';

  const prop = type === 'name'
    ? 'Name'
    : 'propertyAddress';

  return function(string){
    const apiDocs = `api/Documents/${path}?searchString=${string}`;
    const apiClients = `api/Clients/GetAll`;

    const documents = await axios.get(apiDocs);
    const clients = await axios.get(apiClients);

    return documents.map(document => ({
      label: document[prop],
      subLabel: clients.find(c => c.id === document.clientID).firstName,
      value: document
    }));
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
const getNameMatches = searchFor('name');
getNameMatches('foobar');

/* OR */

const getAddrMatches = searchFor('address');
getAddrMatches('foobar');
```